# Soap UI prevent extracting child values when parent is null

Tags: rest, soapui

I'm facing problem, when i need to extract data from JSONPath in Soap UI.

Example:
REST return a JSON with data like:

```
[
   {
      "service": {
         "employee": null
         "id": 123 
      }
   },
   {
      "service": {
         "employee": {
            "name": "Tom"
            "lastName": "Smith"
         }
         "id": 124
      }
   }
]
```

Then i want to extract name with code:

```
$.[0].employee.name
```

The problem is when `employee` is null, the extract testStep fails.
I thought that checking box `Set null on missing source` will solve my problem. When TestStep is running separately it return null as expected, but running in TestCase it fails.

Is there any way to handle that problem? Thanks.

Comment: To me sounds wrong to access a property of a null object ...

Comment: you extract the name in a groovy step ?